# extract quarter from date variable in Stata

Tags: date, stata

I am trying to extract the quarter from a date variable that looks like `dat` in the following example:

```
clear all

input str20 str
    "12Jan1998"
    "29Dec2000"
end

gen dat = date(str, "DMY")
format dat %tdDD-NN-CCYY
```

I am trying to use the `quarter()` function, like in:

```
gen quart = quarter(dofq(dat))
```

What I get is clearly wrong. Can you please suggest a way to solve this?
According to the example, what I would like to get in the end is 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you constructed a daily date, all you need is `quarter()`.  I use here `daily()` not `date()`. It's the same function, but the name is more specific.

```
. clear all

. input str9 str

           str
  1. "12Jan1998"
  2. "29Dec2000"
  3. end

. gen date = daily(str, "DMY")

. format date %tdDD-NN-CCYY

. gen quarter = quarter(date) 

. list  

     +----------------------------------+
     |       str         date   quarter |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 12Jan1998   12-01-1998         1 |
  2. | 29Dec2000   29-12-2000         4 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The `help quarter` documentation tells us that it accepts as an argument "**%td** dates" so you befuddled it by giving it an argument converted from that to a "**%tq** date". So

```
gen quart = quarter(dat)
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Oh well, at least the answer's the same.

Comment: There have been too many times when I've posted and then refreshed my browser to see your definitive thoughts ahead of my tardy and incomplete musings. At least I have the earlier timestamp this time, while still lacking in definitiveness.